# Циолковский — происхождение фамилии

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Собственно, вот. Хотелось бы знать, от какого слова может происходить фамилия знаменитого ученого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это польская фамилия, предки ученого происходили из городка Циолково, восходяшего к  cielę, cielak - теленок, бычок.